# difference between AjaxCommandButton and HtmlAjaxCommandButton

Tags: java, jsf, ajax4jsf

I just have a question about the difference between those two classes :

- `org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.jsp.AjaxCommandButton`
- `org.ajax4jsf.component.html.HtmlAjaxCommandButton`

I am actually using `HtmlAjaxCommandButton` to create dynamically Ajax commandbuttons, and it works fine, but when using the other class `org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.jsp.AjaxCommandButton`, it seems that it has another purpose! I just want to clear things up!

What is the difference between them? And when do we should use this and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one in `taglib` package is a subclass of [`UIComponentTag`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/webapp/UIComponentTag.html) which thus represents the sole JSP tag `<a4j:commandButton>`. It basically definies all available attributes. The one in `component` package is a subclass of [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) which thus represents the concrete JSF component which is associated with the JSP tag. The JSF component definies the decoding (postback processing) and encoding (HTML rendering) behaviors via the renderer. The JSP tag is basically the "mediator" between the JSF component tree and the JSP file.

When dynamically creating JSF components, you should not be manually creating JSP tags. They are not supposed to end up in the JSF component tree.

Note that Facelets, the successor of JSP, does not require those `UIComponentTag` classes anymore. They are totally absent in Facelets.

Comment: Thanks a lot BalusC, taht was helpful !